# Python - Comparing datetime object to next in a list

Tags: python, list, datetime, compare

I'm looping through a list that has datetime objects stored and comparing the current element to next. I am having trouble assigning the next element to a variable.

Code:

```
for p in Monray:
    if (MonBool == False):
        MonBool = True
        MonStartTimeBlock = p
        MonFirstPro = p
        Nextone = Monray[p+1]
```

Error:

```
unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.datetime' and 'int'
```

Seems it is trying to add 1 int to a datetime object rather than accessing the element at "p+1".

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Do you actually use Nextone anywhere else? It might be easier to just remove it. Remember p here refers to the actual value and not the index.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. I do use Nextone, but I won't be using it after the below comment :)

Answer (score 0):

`p` is the element, not its index, so you can't use `p+1` to get the next element.

You can use `zip()` to pair up the elements of the list with a slice starting with the second element.

```
for first_day, next_day in zip(Monray, Monray[1:]):
    # code that uses the days
```

Comment: Hey man,

Thank you for the response. I will give zip() a go, thanks! It's great learning new things with python.